OpenSearch (discover) filter to show last result
I'm using Opensearch dashboard > discover.
I added a few filters and I'm getting 2 hits.
I want to add a filter to show me the last hit only (sorting by time).
I tried:
"size": 1,
but I'm still getting more than 1 results.
seems like "size" is not affecting the results.
How can I display only the last hit?

If you set the size: 1 you should get only 1 result. Did you press control+enter or cmd+enter after set the size? Please send a screenshot and let me check

Thank you, I did click the Refresh button (CTRL + ENTER .. etc.) - still 2 results.
This is how it looks like, I have a few filters, and this is the relevant one, filtered by timestamp:

https://imgur.com/W4EBEeA

In addition, when I Click "inspect" I see that the after refreshing the query - something overrides my "size" definition and turns it to "500"

The size parameter inside of the filter doesn't work. You have two options. First, you can create visualization and set the size 1 in the settings in visualization. The second option is adjusting the size in opensearch dasboard advanced settings if it's exist. I'm saying if it's exist because I know it's exist in Kibana. https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/management/advanced-settings/

Thank you Musab, Which Visualization do I need to choose to get the one like in the screenshot I added in my previous comment?

You can use datatables. https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/visualize/viz-index/#data-tables

Thanks, this will require me to rewrite all settings, i’ll try to find a preset

You're welcome.
